# How to detect and get less or many (.*) syntax in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a syntax `{deck:name}(main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)(side skills)`

Example I have a long content with (main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)(side skills) and (main deck)(extra deck)(side deck) and (main deck)(extra deck) and (main deck):

```
 I have a deck {deck:Sorcery Conduit}(Elementsaber Molehu@2; Aleister the Invoker@3; Elementsaber Nalu)(Invoked Purgatrio@3; Invoked (Cocytus); Invoked Caliga@2)(Artifact Lancea@2; Bad Aim@3)(Destiny Draw>(Yami Yugi)), next deck is {deck:Sorcery Conduit}(Elementsaber Molehu@2; Aleister the Invoker@3; Elementsaber Nalu)(Invoked Purgatrio@3; Invoked (Cocytus); Invoked Caliga@2)(Artifact Lancea@2; Bad Aim@3), okay great and next is {deck:Sorcery Conduit}(Elementsaber Molehu@2; Aleister the Invoker@3; Elementsaber Nalu)(Invoked Purgatrio@3; Invoked (Cocytus); Invoked Caliga@2), finally is {deck:Sorcery Conduit}(Elementsaber Molehu@2; Aleister the Invoker@3; Elementsaber Nalu)
```

I want to use preg_match to check if this syntax exist or not first, if have then I do next things.

```
if (strpos($string, "{deck:") !== false){ // have {deck and do next

 if (preg_match("#{deck:(.*)}\((.*)\)\((.*)\)\((.*)\)\((.*)\)#ismU", $string)) { // have 4 syntax
    echo '(main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)(side skills)';
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
       echo 'do something';
    }
 }else if (preg_match("#{deck:(.*)}\((.*)\)\((.*)\)\((.*)\)#ismU", $content)) { // have 3 syntax 
    echo '(main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)';
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
       echo 'do samething above';
    }
 }else if (preg_match("#{deck:(.*)}\((.*)\)\((.*)\)#ismU", $content)) { // have 2 syntax 
    echo '(main deck)(extra deck)';
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
       echo 'do samething above';
    }
 }else if (preg_match("#{deck:(.*)}\((.*)\)#ismU", $content)) { // have 1 syntax 
    echo '(main deck)';
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
       echo 'do samething above';
    }
 }   
}
```

As you can see my code very long and not useful, I have to use many if else like this, even many loop inside them with the same code with those if else.
Please help me short this code, because my code just do samething!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `preg_match_all` here with the following regex pattern:

```regex
\{deck:(\w+)\}(\(.*?\))(\(.*?\))(\(.*?\))?(\(.*?\))?
```

This matches your input pattern with the side deck and side skills components being made optional.  That is, the above pattern should match all expected input variations.  The difference which would show up would be in the number of capture groups available.

Sample PHP script:

```php
$inputs = array("{deck:name}(main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)(side skills) blah blah {deck:name}(hot wheels)(other stuff)(side deck) blah blah {deck:name}(hello)(world) blah");
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    preg_match_all("/\{deck:\w+\}\(.*?\)\(.*?\)(?:\(.*?\))?(?:\(.*?\))?/", $input, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
        preg_match_all("/\{deck:(\w+)\}(\(.*?\))(\(.*?\))(\(.*?\))?(\(.*?\))?/", $val, $more_matches);
        echo $input . ":\n";
        if ($more_matches[2][0]) {
            echo "main deck is defined: " . $more_matches[2][0] . "\n";
        }
        if ($more_matches[3][0]) {
            echo "extra deck is defined: " . $more_matches[3][0] . "\n";
        }
        if ($more_matches[4][0]) {
            echo "side deck is defined :" . $more_matches[4][0] . "\n";
        }
        if ($more_matches[5][0]) {
            echo "side skills are defined: " . $more_matches[5][0] . "\n";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
{deck:name}(main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)(side skills) blah blah {deck:name}(hot wheels)(other stuff)(side deck) blah blah {deck:name (hello)(world) blah:
main deck is defined: (main deck)
extra deck is defined: (extra deck)
side deck is defined :(side deck)
side skills are defined: (side skills)

{deck:name}(main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)(side skills) blah blah {deck:name}(hot wheels)(other stuff)(side deck) blah blah {deck:name}(hello)(world) blah:
main deck is defined: (hot wheels)
extra deck is defined: (other stuff)
side deck is defined :(side deck)

{deck:name}(main deck)(extra deck)(side deck)(side skills) blah blah {deck:name}(hot wheels)(other stuff)(side deck) blah blah {deck:name}(hello)(world) blah:
main deck is defined: (hello)
extra deck is defined: (world)
```

Comment: how i can detect this $inputs in my long string bro ? @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Well `preg_match_all`, as I have used it above, will find _all_ such matching strings in your input of any length.  It would be up to you and your own logic how you want to handle multiple matches, etc.

Comment: $content = $my_long_string;
preg_match_all("/\{deck:(\w+)\}(\(.*?\))(\(.*?\))(\(.*?\))?(\(.*?\))?/", $content, $matches);
like this bro ?

Comment: I recant what I said above.  Check my updated answer for an approach.

Comment: I tried $inputs = array('{deck:Sorcery Conduit}(Elementsaber Molehu@2; Aleister the Invoker@3; Elementsaber Nalu; Elementsaber Malo; Cosmic Cyclone@3; Invocation@2; Palace of the Elemental Lords@3; Fiendish Chain@3; Treacherous Trap Hole@2)(Invoked Purgatrio@3; Invoked Cocytus; Invoked Caliga@2)(Artifact Lancea@2; Bad Aim@3)(Destiny Draw>Yami Yugi)');  
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
  preg_match_all("/\{deck:\w+\}\(.*?\)\(.*?\)(?:\(.*?\))?(?:\(.*?\))?/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
 }

But no result bro

Comment: I have given you working code which you may use at the end of my answer.  Reload your page in case you haven't done so already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239528/discussion-between-tanker-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I have updated the complete answer now.  [Here is a working demo](https://rextester.com/TDU57889) which you can review.

Comment: I tried but my string not show any result in array bro
$inputs = array('{deck:Sorcery Conduit}(Elementsaber Molehu@2; Aleister the Invoker@3; Elementsaber Nalu; Elementsaber Malo; Cosmic Cyclone@3; Invocation@2; Palace of the Elemental Lords@3; Fiendish Chain@3; Treacherous Trap Hole@2)(Invoked Purgatrio@3; Invoked Cocytus; Invoked Caliga@2)(Artifact Lancea@2; Bad Aim@3)(Destiny Draw>Yami Yugi)');
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    preg_match_all("/\{deck:\w+\}\(.*?\)\(.*?\)(?:\(.*?\))?(?:\(.*?\))?/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
}  

result:     [0] => Array